# Alternative to a basin wrench?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, faucet, tools

I'm in need of a tool to tighten a nut such as shown below:

[image]

Because of the tight space (area below the basin faucet), I'm never had success with the many wrenches that I used. At last, I came to know about the basin wrench which (as shown in the pic above) seem to be just what I'm looking for.

### The problem

I'm from India and I cannot find this wrench anywhere in the online market (Amazon shows a couple results but they are from global store and cost a lot). I also tried a couple of local shops but they didn't seem to recognize it.

So, is there an alternative to this tool that I can get it at my place?

### Some more information

These are the wrenches that I've tried and failed owing to space constraints.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This comment is likely not what you want to hear. Disconnect the drain line and the water supply lines. Lift the sink off the counter top and tighten the fittings with a conventional wrench. It seems like a lot of work but with your limited sources of supply it may be your best option.

Comment: No Harbor Freight in India, or other place that sells cheap, Chinese-made tools?  No hardware or plumbing supply sources?  One thing to try is using a long crescent or open-end wrench, but go in parallel with the hose, perpendicular to the nut, so you're grabbing just two opposite flat sides.  Grab the other end of the wrench with another tool to get some leverage, and twist it like a basin wrench.

Comment: @mikes I'll keep that as the last option when nothing seems to be possible

Comment: You should be careful not to over-tighten it. I would offer that with sufficient grip and hand strength, hand-tight may be sufficient. Fixer1234's and mikes solutions are good choices. 

Also, to be clear, the basin wrench in the image is in the "loosen" mode, not the "tighten" orientation.

Answer (score 4):

Another wrench type for this situation is the socket type. I have seen some in plastic that may come with the faucet. [socket basin wrench](https://www.grainger.com/product/45W754?cm_mmc=PPC:%20Google%20PLA&s_kwcid=AL!2966!3!50916805677!!!g!71851510759!&ef_id=Wb6hZAAABW5VfXMN:20180723125056:s)

Here is an ingenious tool [video to use of plastic tube wrench](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rdT7yZN20OQ) and [another video of same Rigid wrench](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBK83pN5ahs)

I think I have seen simple ones that are little more than an 8 inch long tube with a slot along the length to slip over the supply hose. One end fits the nut holding the faucet and some other wrench is used on the bottom end. It is possible that you could have one fabricated locally out of steel pipe. The bottom end could be turned by pliers or a pipe wrench. The upper end could have wrenching flats soldered (or glued) inside the pipe.

Comment: Looks good, but again the same problem. Not available locally :( There is the option to bulk order (min 100 pieces or so) but that obviously won't be an option for me.

Comment: Didn't mean to suggest you  wud ordr 100 but want'd to show pic. There is another tool ment for removin' vlve stms. One could posbly have slot cut locally. Is this a metric nut?

Answer (score 3):

There is also the ["crow's foot" type wrenches](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dDyScQP4eLg)

[image]

Comment: Looks good, but again the same problem. Not available locally :( There is the option to bulk order (min 100 pieces or so) but that obviously won't be an option for me.

Answer (score 2):

make a socket wrench out of a piece of pvc pipe, sized for the nut you are working with, cut slots on the end of the pipe so that the shoulders of the nut lock in to the slots of the pvc pipe. If working with a plastic wing nut, simply cut two slots in the pipe that fit the nut. If you don't have pvc, same concept with a piece of wood will work, but more work involved making the wrench.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: @Daniel I miss "Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming" :)

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Yeah, sorry. I got burned out and stepped away. Looks like you're doing fine without me, though; keep it up.